# Use ajax and a unique id to load data from a php file

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

my problem is that I have to enter an id in my html form and then on pressing the go button an ajax query must be fired which retrieves data from a php file and auto fills the remaining input in my html form.
I'm starting by returning static data later on I have to retrieve data from a database.

I'm new at using ajax jquery so not able to work it out.

HTML form and AJAX Jquery

```
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>AJAX</title>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <form>
                    Id:<input type="text" id="id">
                    Name:<input type="text" id="name">
                    Mobile:<input type="text" id="mob">
                    Email:<input type="text" id="email">
                    <button id="bgd">GO!</button>
                </form>

                <script type="text/javascript">

                        $("#bgd").click(function(){
                            $.ajax({
                            type: "post",
                            url: "im-form/phpdata.php",
                            dataType: "json",
                            data:{
                               id:'id',
                               name: 'name',
                               mob: 'mob',
                               email: 'email'
                            },
                        async: true,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(results) {

                            var obj = $results;
                            var name = obj.name;
                            var mob= obj.mob;
                            var email= obj.email;
                             $("#name").val(name);
                             $("#mob").val(mob);
                             $("#email").val(email);

                            }
                        });
                    });
                </script>
            </body>
        </html>
```

php file

```
    <?php
        $id =5;
        $name="goku";
        $mob=9000;
        $email="goku@dragonball.com";

        $results=array('id'=>$id,'name'=>$name,'mob'=>$mob,'email'=>$email);

            if($results)
            {
                 echo json_encode($results);

            }

    ?>
```

Comment: What is `bName` and `bgd`?

Comment: missing variables into this code..Please post your full code.

Comment: sorry for that!

Comment: Firstly, you need to remove `alert("HI!");`.

Answer (score 0):

You have errors in your code,

```
$("#bgd").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    // alert("HI!"); remove this
    type: "post", // use in small case
    url: "im-form/phpdata.php",
    dataType: "json", // dataType not datatype, check the T in camel case
    data:{
        id:$('#id').val(), // get input values here
        name: $('#name').val(),
        mob: $('#mob').val(),
        email: $('#email').val()
    },
    //async: true,// be default it is asynchronous
    cache: false,
    success: function(results) {
      //var obj = $.parseJSON(results); // no need to use parseJSON, as dataType is already used for it
      var obj = results,
          id = obj.id, // no need of [] as it is single object
          name = obj.name,
          mob= obj.mob,
          email= obj.email;
      $("#bName").val(name);
      $("#blPd").val(id);

    } // remove semicolon after success
  });
});
```

PHP code should be like,

```
<?php

    $id =5; // use $_POST['id'] here
    $name="goku"; // $_POST['name']
    $mob=9000; // $_POST['mob']
    $email="goku@dragonball.com"; // $_POST['email']
    // make an associative array here
    $results=array('id'=>$id,'name'=>$name,'mob'=>$mob,'email'=>$email);
    if($results) {
        echo json_encode($results);
    }
?>
```

Comment: i have made some changes . my problem is that by using the id i need to get all the remaining details.